# Search item in list in another list in C#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, frequency

I want to match any string items in the list with substring items in another list, then put substring and repetition in the dictionary without for loop because the substring list contains 24345000 cells.

```
 string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(@"..\Raw Data", "*");
 Dictionary<string, int> freq = new Dictionary<string, int>();
 var letters= File.ReadAllLines(@"..\letters.txt").ToList();
 foreach (string folder in folders)
        {
            string name_folder = Path.GetFileName(folder);

            string[] N_F = Directory.GetFiles(@"..\items\" + folder, "*.txt");
            foreach (string f in N_F)
            {
                List<string> s = File.ReadAllText(f).Split(' ').ToList();
                s.RemoveAll(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace);
                foreach(string t in letters)
                    if(s.Contains(t))
                if (freq.ContainsKey(t))
                        freq[t]++;
                    else
                        freq[t] = 1;
            }
}
```

Comment: Example input and output

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a way to search count of occurrence of words from a list in another list.

```
// Sample Data 
var letters = new string[] { "Apple", "Orange", "Mango", "Cherry" };
var masterList = new string[] 
                { "Apple", "Tea", "Mango", "Apple", "Wheat", "Mango",
                  "Bread", "Orange", "Mango", "Apple", "Orange", "Mango",
                  "Apple", "Bread", "Mango", "Apple", "Bread", "Tea"
                };
```

You can try:

```
var freq = words.Select(w => new { Word = w, Count = masterList.Count(m => m == w) })
                              .ToList();
```

`freq` will contain:

```
Word = Apple    Count = 5
Word = Orange    Count = 2
Word = Mango    Count = 5
Word = Cherry    Count = 0
```